# Autovectorization alignment

Tags: c++, intel, memory-alignment

From Intel's [Compiler Autovectorization Guide](http://download-software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/CompilerAutovectorizationGuide.pdf) there's an example related to alignment that I don't understand. The code is

```
double a[N], b[N];
...
for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
  a[i+1] = b[i] * 3;
```

And it says

> If the first element of both arrays is aligned at a 16-byte boundary,
>   then either an unaligned load of elements from **b** or an unaligned
>   store of elements into **a**, has to be used after vectorization.
>   However, the programmer can enforce the alignment shown below, which
>   will result in two aligned access patterns after vectorization
>   (assuming an 8-byte size for doubles)

```
_declspec(align(16, 8)) double a[N];
_declspec(align(16, 0)) double b[N];
```

How to see where the misalignment comes after vectorization? Wouldn't the alignment depend on the size of the arrays?

Comment: Hmm, yes, a code snippet that intentionally indexes a[] out of bounds is indeed quite confusing.  What I think it is try to say that this loop always causes a misaligned access.  If b[i] is aligned then a[i+1] will be mis-aligned.  Or the other way around.  So what it proposes to do about it is to get a[] intentionally mis-aligned in memory, off by 8.  So now both accesses are aligned.

Comment: So the example by itself doesn't have a misalignment? I mean, I don't get how would it produce a misalignment or why would it produce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hans Passant essentially covers all the right ideas, but let me explain a bit more:

Say `a` and `b` are both aligned to 16 bytes. say, they have address 0x100 and 0x200, for the sake of example.

Now, let's see how the code looks like with `i=3` (odd) and `i=6` (even)...

`a[i+1] = b[i] * 3;` will do `[0x120] = [0x318] * 3` (i=3, sizeof double is 8)

or

`a[i+1] = b[i] * 3;` will do `[0x138] = [0x330] * 3`

In both cases, either the left hand side or the right hand side is aligned, while the other one is misaligned (aligned accesses would always end in 0 in hex, misaligned something else).

Now... Let's purposefully misalign `a` to a 8 modulo 16 address (say to 0x108, to keep our example).

Let's see how the code looks like with `i=3` (odd) and `i=6` (even)...

`a[i+1] = b[i] * 3;` will do `[0x128] = [0x318] * 3` (i=3, sizeof double is 8)

or

`a[i+1] = b[i] * 3;` will do `[0x140] = [0x330] * 3`

both keep the actual accesses aligned and misaligned at the same time.

Comment: I got it ! Finally, the 8 modulo 16. 8 is because the data type used (in our case `double`) and the 16 is because the addresses for a certain architecture are aligned to that, right?

Comment: Actually, what would happen if the array is aligned to a, say, 8 or 32  byte boundary? How does that relate to all of this?

Comment: Well, you can do the math to get convinced: a 32 byte aligned address is 16 byte aligned, so no change there. an 8 byte aligned can either have an address of 0 modulo 16, or 8 modulo 16, so you don't know. It's up to the allocator implementation...

Comment: I think I didn't ask what I was trying to ask hehe, sorry. I wanted to know who or what dictates what the boundary should be, but reading over the internet apparently that depends on the architecture.